# Right join isn't pulling in all rows from right table

Tags: sql-server, join, dbeaver

I've got two tables for a call center in a Microsoft SQL Server database, fact_queue, that has the number of calls received, and dim_interval, which is used to convert the interval number (0-95) into time stamps (e.g. 07:15-07:30). It's set up this way so you can easily change the timezone data is being pulled in.

I'm trying to get a result which will show me all 96 intervals regardless of if there's a call or not, but it's not working as expected.

Here's an example of what's in the tables:

Fact_Queue

| date_id | queue_id | interval_id | calls_offered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7780 | 40 | 0 | 1 |
| 7780 | 40 | 2 | 5 |
| 7780 | 40 | 3 | 6 |
| 7780 | 40 | 5 | 10 |

Dim_Interval

| interval_id | interval_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 00:00 - 00:15 |
| 1 | 00:15 - 00:30 |
| 2 | 00:30 - 00:45 |
| 3 | 00:45 - 01:00 |
| -- | -- |
| 95 | 23:45 - 24:00 |

I've played around with a couple variations of a query and I believe the following should work, but it isn't

```
SELECT dim_interval.interval_name
      ,fact_queue.offered_calls
FROM dim_interval
RIGHT JOIN fact_queue
  ON fact_queue.interval_id = dim_interval.interval_id
WHERE fact_queue.date_id= '7780'
  AND fact_queue.queue_id = '40'
ORDER BY dim_interval.interval_id
```

This just results in

| interval_name | calls_offered |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00 - 00:15 | 1 |
| 00:30 - 00:45 | 5 |
| 00:45 - 01:00 | 6 |
| 01:15 - 01:30 | 10 |

but what I want is

| interval_name | calls_offered |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00 - 00:15 | 1 |
| 00:15 - 00:30 | null |
| 00:30 - 00:45 | 5 |
| 00:45 - 01:00 | 6 |
| 01:00 - 01:15 | null |

Why is the query not working? If it matters I'm using DBeaver version 21.0.3.202104181339

Comment: You need to `left join` to Fact_Queue, include the `where` criteria on the join.

Comment: Every `right join` can be expressed as a `left join`, and should be, because most people find it easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet `dim_interval JOIN fact_queue`, you've place the dimension table on the left, not the right.  As you want all the dimension table's rows, this means you want a left outer join...

```
FROM dim_interval LEFT JOIN fact_queue
```

That only gets you half way there though, because the WHERE clause is applied After the join. This means the WHERE clause would filter out the results which have NULLs.

So, you need to do the filtering During the join...

```
SELECT dim_interval.interval_name
      ,fact_queue.offered_calls
FROM dim_interval
LEFT JOIN fact_queue
  ON fact_queue.interval_id = dim_interval.interval_id
  AND fact_queue.date_id= '7780'
  AND fact_queue.queue_id = '40'
ORDER BY dim_interval.interval_id
```

Some people prefer to do the filtering Before the join, but that's not necessary and actually yields the same execution plan...

```
SELECT dim_interval.interval_name
      ,fact_queue.offered_calls
FROM dim_interval
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM fact_queue
    WHERE date_id= '7780'
    AND queue_id = '40' 
) AS fact_queue
  ON fact_queue.interval_id = dim_interval.interval_id
ORDER BY dim_interval.interval_id
```

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie

I flipped the tables and did
```SELECT dim_interval.interval_name
      ,fact_queue.offered_calls
FROM mart.fact_queue fact_queue
RIGHT JOIN mart.dim_interval dim_interval
  ON fact_queue.interval_id = dim_interval.interval_id
  AND fact_queue.date_id= '7780'
  AND fact_queue.queue_id = '40'
ORDER BY dim_interval.interval_id```

so I'm now getting what I want.

Why does

```AND fact_queue.date_id= '7780'
  AND fact_queue.queue_id = '40'```

have to be part of the join for this to work instead of part of a WHERE clause?

Comment: @SpencerRay - Because WHERE clauses are applied After the join, to the values as they would otherwise appear in the results. By that point you would have rows with NULLs in the `fact_queue` columns, where there was no fact record to OUTER JOIN on to the dimension record. As NULL never equals anything the WHERE clause would therefore exclude that resulting row. In effect, outing that filter in the WHERE clause turns the OUTER JOIN back in to an INNER JOIN. So, you need to filter the fact table Before the join or During the join.

Comment: Also, as per another comment, RIGHT JOINs are uncommonly used. While there is no technical reason to avoid them, for maintainability and readability, using LEFT JOINs is generally clearer and preferred. Where a LEFT JOIN can fit the logic, it should be given precedence over RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! It's not clicked and problem is solved!